# Server won't start after installing IBM Rational CLM solution with an evaluation topology

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, ibm-rational

I have been trying to install and run the IBM Rational Solution for CLM with an evaluation topology for the purposes of performing a demonstration of the software.

I am able to proceed through all of the installation steps, but once I reach the step of starting the server, it does not start.

When I try to start the server, a new command prompt window opens, but closes immediately. The log files under /server/tomcat/logs are not updated.

I was initially setting up the server in a Windows 7 VMware virtual machine. I have since tried to set it up in a new vm running CentOS, but I got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated by [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/79599/tomcat-server-not-starting?sort=votes&page=2), the only way to debug this is to put a lot of "echo" in the starting script:

> What really helped me when I had this problem was to add echo statements to the `.bat` files to see how far it's getting.
>   In my situation, it got all the way to the end of the `catalina.bat` file, and I printed out the final run commands on the screen.
>   When I called that same command manually in a dos window, I was able to see what error was being returned since it didn't close after a split second.  Perhaps that approach would help you as well.

It usually is a memory issue.

If not - a few more things to check:

> 1. Disk space - do you have much disk space available - esp. the location of your TEMP environment variable.
> 2. When Ralph talked about starting as Administrator - he meant starting your DOS shell using the right-button "Run as administrator" option on the shell.
> 3. Do you have any firewall settings preventing access to ports like 9443, 9080 and more obscure ones like 9003?
> 4. Does the user who installed RTC have read/write access to those c:\ibm directories and sub-dirs.  I have seen Tomcat not start if it could not write to the log files (bit of a meaningless question as you have catalina logs).

[That thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/93111/error-in-tomcat-and-unable-connect-to-jts) confirms the memory issue:

> Please check https://jazz.net/library/article/811 for your patch level of the server OS. The document also points out 8GB RAM as a minimum.
>
> If nothing appears in the logs it is a severe Tomcat or JVM issue. You may be facing RAM issues. i would suggest to look into the core dumps for indicators what happens.
>
> Some other hints:
>
> - Don't install in Program Files use /IBM/ or something
> - If this is not a test system use DB2 instead of derby. Derby is only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Looks like memory was the issue.  The other points are good advice, though.  Will have to file those away in case they're needed in the future.  Thanks Von!